# Why did the "Jews" separate from their wives 3 days before Matan Torah?

Tags: gentiles, marriage, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, kabbalat-hatorah

If a Jewish Man has intimate relations with his wife, and then the seed escapes the woman's body she becomes known as a Paletes Shichvas Zerah. Now, if that occurs within 3 days she becomes Tamei. If the seed escaped after 3 days then she's Tahor and it's fine. However, if she has intimate relations with a Goy, then she never becomes Tamei no matter when the seed escapes from her body. Being that the reason why men would separate from their wives 3 days before Matan Torah, it makes zero sense to say they had to, because, they weren't Jewish anyways! So what's the pshat?

Comment: Now, you can say the whole shpeil where they were kinda like Jewish more then your avg goy. But cmon, gimme a better pshat pls.

Comment: Why get into a discussion of Zera? Gentiles aren't Tamei Deorayta at all for any reason

Comment: The level of purity required for the *Mattan Torah* was different from standard tamei / taraha considerations. See also where Moshe is ordered to take his shoes off at the burning bush or Yehoshua when speaking to the angel.

Comment: Different, how? @JoshK

Comment: They were Jewish enough to be forbidden to go out and collect the _Mann_ on the _Shabbat_ (and chastised for not obeying) since _Marah_ (for which "גוי ששבת חייב מיתה"), and Jewish enough to eat from the _Qorban Pesach_ in _Mitzrayim_ (of which "כל בן נכר לא יאכל בו ... תושב ושכיר לא יאכל בו"). Why wouldn't they be Jewish enough to require three days to purify (to include a _Poletet Shikhvat Zera_), especially when preparing to stand before God, in the greatest event in [Jewish] history?

Comment: If I knew that or had a source this would be an answer rather than a comment, @Moshe

Comment: Lol @JoshK Gotchu.

Comment: Also the Bnei Yisrael were Jewish enough to be taken out of Egypt right before this

Comment: I hear, good approach @TamirEvan

Comment: @TamirEvan they had already gotten the mitzva of shabbos, which is why they had to keep it (no collecting manna, etc.) but they hadn’t gotten the mitzva of taharah yet- in fact, many of them were probably tamei meis because of the fight with amalek and the lack of para adumah.

Comment: @Loani The question assumes they weren't actually Jews, and thus had no _Tum'ah_ of _Poletet Shikhvat Zera_ to wait three days for. All I'm saying is, if they were Jews enough to receive the _Mitzvot_ of _Pesach_ and _Shabbat_ (that as non-Jews they would have no part in), they were Jews enough for that _Tum'ah_ to apply to them.

Comment: Source for anything mentioned here?

Comment: If you'd like to source it, be my guest @DonielF

Comment: Also, perhaps you could ask according to the Rabbanan that there were only two days of separation: if they were Jews, they needed three, and if they were not Jews, then no days were required at all.

Comment: I think the premise of this question is that am yisrael was nothing special but rather completely indistinct from any other group before matan Torah which I think is obviously false.

Comment: God is a spiritual being. To be able to properly encounter Him, one has to prepare accordingly, setting the spiritual element in full control of its physical aspect, the body, and abstinence is obviously a form of self-control over one's bodily instincts.

Answer (score 2):

One could easily argue that they were fully Jewish not on the 7th of Sivan, but on the 4th. After all, we learn the halachos of conversion from Har Sinai (Yevamos 46b), and, according to R’ Yosi, they washed their clothes, toveled, and sprinkled on the 4th of Sivan, and so they had to have three days (Shabbos 86b-87a).

The Gemara ibid. 86a makes this point explicitly: the one who holds that she’s impure for three days holds like R’ Yosi, and the one who holds that she’s impure for just two days holds like the Chachamim that they separated on the 5th.

Comment: And this is why it’s good practice to check your sources before asking a question: best case scenario, you’ll find your answer right there. Worst case scenario, you’ll at least probably find some information to improve your question.